# PayPal express checkout button - are there different variations/colors?

Tags: button, paypal, express-checkout

In order to use Express Checkout, i [have to use](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECGettingStarted#idbec8c969-cd47-4d23-bb4b-18a5e0c1fd17) button from PayPal's server. But it offers  only one button style: https://www.paypal.com/express-checkout-buttons. It looks really bad on dark background. Is there another "official" page which offers more styles (similar to what FB offers for LIKE button for example)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link is the official page on the latest button styles

https://www.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/logos-buttons

Comment: button string and color can't be customized more?

Comment: @Alex as per a deleted comment.... documentation states "You must put the Express Checkout button on your checkout page."

Comment: Thanks for your response.